# What are the differences in using HDRis (created from HDR Lighting Studio for example) to light your scene verses using Blender's Lights?

Tags: rendering, lighting, hdri

I'm looking at purchasing HDR Lighting Studio and using it with Blender.  For those that don't know, it's a tool used to create your own HDRi map and using it to light your scene.

As appealing as it sounds, I wanted to know what the differences are from using only and HDRi to light your scene, verses using Blender's Lights.

For example, is light calculated differently?  Is there a difference in render time?  I would think one HDRi map would be more performant over using several Blender lights.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: I think the biggest difference would be that HDRI's not only provide pseudo-_Global Lighting_, they also provide _reflections_. Both of these are not available with direct light sources such as point lights - many of these lights only appear as specular dots in reflections, and due to their limited directionality, do not provide great realism from either a reflection or shadow-casting point of view.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett  Sounds like a great benefit.  Thank you for you comment!